# In chrome, my select's CSS animation no longer works unless border's overridden

Tags: css, google-chrome

This seems to be something that started happening with version 83 of Chrome.

In this JSFiddle, the select's background should fade from red to white when the page first loads. However, for some reason I've found this only works when the border property is overridden (uncomment that line in the CSS to see this in action).

https://jsfiddle.net/nqfdx9ug/

HTML:

```
<select class="highlight-and-fade">
    <option>---Select---</option>
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>hello</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select {
  width: 120px;
  
  /* Uncomment below to fix the animation */
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}
        
.highlight-and-fade {
  animation: highlightAndFade 3s linear;
}

@keyframes highlightAndFade {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Anyone have an idea of what changed and why, or if there's a less hacky workaround? Firefox doesn't have this issue for me, nor does Chrome version 81. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome - Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)
This works just fine for me without the border workaround. Maybe your browser is storing cache and that's why it doesn't display properly ([here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) is how to clear cache)

Comment: I'm on this same version and have cleared my cache, but am seeing different behavior. What are you seeing exactly with the JSFiddle? I just noticed that if i expand the menu, I do see the animation on the expanded menu portion. However, with the border workaround, the dropdown animates even when unexpanded. Is that what you're seeing too? I don't quite understand the correlation between the border and the background of that part of the select control!

Comment: oh, so you want the whole element to fade from red to white? I thought you wanted just the options t do that. I have no clue chief. I did some research on it and you seem to be the only person who experienced this. 

I've also tried setting the border: 0px; and it works so if the border bothers you that should work as well. 
I'm sorry I can't give you a clear explanation of why it is the way it is. Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah exactly. I just found that setting the background color to white initially is another way to fix it. Seemingly styling the element in any way pretty much fixes it in these versions of Chrome, making me think it's some strange bug. Thanks anyway for taking a look and researching!